# Bind with d3 events

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

When writing event handlers in d3, is there a way to use a [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) equivalent directly? I don't see `bind` implemented or discussed anywhere in the documentation.

Currently I am doing this:

```
graph = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
    this.svg.append('svg:rect')
        .style('fill', '#f00')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 300);
    this.svg.on('mousedown', function(){return self.mouseDown.call(this, self);})
}
graph.prototype.mouseDown = function (self) {
    /* 'self' is the instance of graph */
    alert(self.svg);
    /* 'this' is the event */
    alert(d3.mouse(this));
}
var g = new graph();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n9uo7vy/)

This works fine. However the use of the anonymous function to use `call` here seems like bad practice, because `bind` would have been able to accomplish this on regular DOM elements (if I had not been using d3 selections). I would prefer to use the d3 selection rather than targeting the underlying DOM element (for consistency, and because `this.svg` is already being attached to the `graph` object).

Since d3's `on` method [appears to be the typical way to assign event listeners](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on), are there any other options for passing data here?

Comment: What do you mean by ``bind``: Is it some well known function? some concept?

Comment: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: OK, I've edited your question. See if you like it.

Comment: Are you looking for [`d3.rebind()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#rebind)?

Comment: why don’t you use `this.mouseDown.bind(this)`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I am basically looking for the d3 equivalent of `body.onclick = function(){alert(this);}.bind(this);` to be able to call both the instance as well as the event, without doing `var self = this;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all stems from the fact that d3 relies on the `this` keyword to point to the DOM element — using `this` almost like another argument passed to the handler function. That "clashes" with the typical use of `this` as a reference to the class instance.

Since `Function.prototype.bind()` is just a way to explicitly set the `this` keyword of a function call, it doesn't solve your issue. In other words, if you need to access both the DOM element and the class instance, you have to set up a secondary variable like `self` to point to one of those two.

That's gotta be at least partially why d3's own classes (e.g. `d3.svg.axis`) don't use the `prototype` way of class declaration, relying instead on closures (as described [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)). So either you switch to that style of class declaration, or you have to keep doing it the way you show in your example. There's also this somewhat more idiomatic variant of your example, but it's still basically the same as what you have:

```
graph = function () {
    this.svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');
    this.svg.on('mousedown', this.mouseDownHandler())
}
graph.prototype.mouseDownHandler = function () {
    /* 'self' is the instance of graph */
    var self = this;
    return function(d, i) {
        /* 'this' is the DOM element */
        alert(d3.mouse(this));

        /* now you can work with both "self" and "this" */
    }
}
var g = new graph();
```

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. I knew I would have to pass both objects but I was hoping I could avoid doing `var self = this;`. I read the article about the preference towards closures/chaining attributes, but the `graph` object is a minor piece of a much larger code base that is already styled with function prototypes